# Datagrid row expand on row click in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have silverlight application in which i have added one toggle button to expand row.at same time i have 2 textbox and 1 button on same row.my toggle button is working fine but when i click on textbox or button rows get expanded which should not be happen.Row must be expand on toggle button click only.plz guide me whr i am wrong.
my toggle button is added like below
.xaml

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
             <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource PlusMinusToggleButtonStyle}"    Loaded="ToggleButton_Loaded" />
       </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

and .cs code is as below

```
 private void ToggleButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleButton button = sender as ToggleButton;
            DataGridRow row = button.FindAncestor<DataGridRow>();  //Custom Extension
            row.SetBinding(DataGridRow.DetailsVisibilityProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding()
            {
                Source = button,
                Path = new PropertyPath("IsChecked"),
                Converter = new VisibilityConverter(),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            });
    }
```

and interface IValueConverter is implemented as below

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value) return Visibility.Visible;
            else return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
                return true;
            else return false;

        }
    }
```

what condition i need to check at convert and ConvertBack.or how i can check clicked object is toggle button and not the other button

Answer (score 0):

You can write the same code which you have written for ToggleButton_Loaded event in the ToggleButton_clicked event then you don't have to check for which button or textBox is clicked.

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource PlusMinusToggleButtonStyle}"    Click="ToggleButton_Clicked" />
```

And .cs code as

```
private void ToggleButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToggleButton button = sender as ToggleButton;
            DataGridRow row = button.FindAncestor<DataGridRow>();  //Custom Extension
            row.SetBinding(DataGridRow.DetailsVisibilityProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding()
            {
                Source = button,
                Path = new PropertyPath("IsChecked"),
                Converter = new VisibilityConverter(),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            });
    }
```

Comment: not working.When i click on other button then ConvertBack is invoked.and expand the row.